# Try to rejoin a client to a specific room after reconnect

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd, multiuserchat

I successfully created a muc service and create a room.
After i create the room "testroom@conference.xmpp.messenger.local" i enter the room with my client "client@xmpp.messenger.local".
(My client is also the owner of the muc room)
in this case it works and i am able to send any messages to the muc room.

My problem came up if i reload the page and reconnect to my ejabberd server.
After reconnect i read all rooms of a client and try to join the room with the following presence stanza (described in XEP-0045 // 16.7.1):

```
<presence to='testroom@conference.xmpp.messenger.local'>
  <x xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc'/>
</presence>
```

Now i get the error code 409 which contains the following error message: 
"That nickname is registered by another person"

i can't understand why it says i registered this nickname by another person -> it is the same person

btw i also tried to re-enter with:

```
<presence
    from='client@xmpp.messenger.local'
    id='n13mt3l'
    to='testroom@conference.xmpp.messenger.local'>
  <x xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/muc'/>
</presence>
```

At least i tried to enter the room with different nicknames, but this causes an instant disconnect without any error message.

I hope anyone else can figure out the problem and could help me to find a solution.

Comment: You should mention what ejabberd version you are using. Also, that behaviour looks strange, so it could be some custom configuration in mod_muc that you haven't mentioned. And finaly, as you are using a custom client, it could be something undesired in that client, so you should try with a well-known client (like Gajim or Psi), and compare the XMPP stanzas it sends with your client.

Comment: Thanks for your reply
I am using the ejabberd version 18.12 and the following xmpp bosh client : 
https://github.com/kdcro101/xmpp-bosh-client

did you mean my configuration when i create a room or in my config file  ?

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.
I had to choose an resource while connecting any client to the ejabberd server.

I thought this is not required, but now it works.